# Class Loaders in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a 2 different project :

1) Library Project called BaseLibrary:

```
public class DefaultProps
    {
        public virtual String getAppName()
        {
            return "XYZ";
        }

        public virtual int getAppVersion()
        {
             return 1;
        }
    }

class BaseSettings : DefaultProps
    {
        public virtual string getAppName()
        {
            return base.getAppName();
        }

        public virtual int getAppVersion()
        {
            return base.getAppVersion();
        }
    }
```

2) Child Project which has a reference of Library project:

```
 using BaseLibrary;
    class AppSettings : DefaultProps
    {
        public override string getAppName()
        {
            return "ABC";
        }

    }
```

I am working on `Windows Phone app development`, when I run the child project I want the getAppName to be displayed as `"ABC"` but instead of that its displaying the default value in BaseLibrary `"XYZ".`
And also if the property is not displayed in child app then it should take the default property value from BaseLibrary.

In java we use `Class Loaders` to achieve this, how to achieve this in C#,Visual Studio 2012.

**EDIT**
In BaseLibrary in MainPage.xaml.cs file

```
BaseSettings baseSettings = new BaseSettings ();
            string appName = baseSettings .getAppName();
            int appVersion = baseSettings .getAppVersion();

            App_Name.Text = appName;
            App_Version.Text = "" + appVersion;
```

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of the Settings class?

Comment: If you are actually using class loaders in Java to solve this problem, then IMO you are really abusing class loaders.

Comment: I don't see how classloaders would be relevant even in Java. It sounds like you're creating an instance of the `Settings` class in the core library project, rather than the `Settings` class in the child project. It would almost certainly make your code easier to understand if you gave the two types different names, given that they *are* different types. Also, there's no point in overriding a method just to explicitly call the base method, and your methods don't follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: in my MainPage.xaml , please see my edit

Comment: @KirkWoll how to achieve this in c# then ?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I am creating object of settings in library project, and yes I am very new to c# so I am still learning

Comment: So start by giving the classes different names. Then it'll be a lot easier to tell what class you're actually creating an instance of. (And I agree with Kirk - giving different classes the same name in Java and using classloaders to load the "right" one would be a mistake too...)

Comment: @JonSkeet then how to solve can you please suggest me, or show me any example ?

Comment: I've said: use different class names to start with, and potentially specify the *exact* type name (including assembly reference) to instantiate in the XAML. You haven't really given us enough context to help you further - but if you're new to C# then it sounds like you may have bitten off too complicated a task to start with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45821/discussion-between-user2056563-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: `BaseSettings baseSettings = new BaseSettings ();` is *always* going to create an instance of `BaseSettings()`. How could `baseSettings.getAppName()` *ever* return "ABC"? As I said, I think you've bitten off more than you can chew for the moment, and that you should probably learn a bit more C# before attempting a multi-platform project like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that's what I am trying to tell you that, its displaying the value XYZ, I want the value from child project, how can I achieve this?